# Citrus-Framework: Possible to send SOAP attachment from server simulation with Java DSL?

Tags: simulation, mtom, citrus-framework

For a component test with **Citrus Framework** I **simulate a backend system** that is called through **SOAP**.

```
<citrus-ws:server id="backendSimulationServer"
                port="8080"
                auto-start="true"
                interceptors="serverInterceptors"
                timeout="5000"/>
```

I get SOAP requests from the component and send back responses.

```
    runner.receive(action -> action.endpoint("backendSimulationServer")
            .name("search-request")
            .payload(new ClassPathResource("testfiles/search-request-expectation.xml"))
    );

    runner.send(action -> action.endpoint("backendSimulationServer")
            .name("search-response")
            .payload(new ClassPathResource("testfiles/search-response.xml"))
    );
```

But now I have to answer to a request with an **MTOM attachment response**. I found the citrus example that uses `.attachment` on a `soap().client()`, but **`.attachment` is not available** for my server simulation.

Is this possible with Java DSL or do I re-write the testcase in XML DSL to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both SOAP attachment and MTOM enabled methods are also available on server components in Citrus. This should do the trick for you:

```
soap().server(soapMtomServer)
      .send()
      .mtomEnabled(true)
      .attachment("IMAGE", "application/octet-stream", new ClassPathResource("com/consol/citrus/hugeImageData.png"))
      .payload("<image:addImage xmlns:image=\"http://www.citrusframework.org/imageService/\">" +
                   "<image>cid:IMAGE</image>" +
               "</image:addImage>");
```